# C# WPF Multithreading issue - program freezing

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I currently have a program that allows me to move different images (furniture) around a canvas (room), but I want to make it so that you can only move the furniture when it's selected from a list box. The issue I'm currently facing is that the program freezes whenever I go to move an image that is not selected, which is due to the UI thread being too busy. Here is the code:

```
private FurnitureImage draggedImage;
    private Point mousePosition;
    private bool ShouldMove = false;

    private void CanvasRoomMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = e.Source as FurnitureImage;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() => {
            try
            {

                    if (image != null && CanvasRoom.CaptureMouse() && (Rooms[listBoxRooms.SelectedIndex].Furniture[listBoxFurniture.SelectedIndex].Equals(image)))
                    {
                        ShouldMove = true;
                        mousePosition = e.GetPosition(CanvasRoom);
                        draggedImage = image;
                        Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 1);
                        //Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
                    }               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().ToString()); 
            }
        }));

    }
private void CanvasRoomMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        if (draggedImage != null && ShouldMove)
        {
            CanvasRoom.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 0);
            draggedImage = null;
        }
    }
private void CanvasRoomMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedImage != null && ShouldMove)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition(CanvasRoom);
            var offset = position - mousePosition;
            mousePosition = position;
            double NewXPos = Canvas.GetLeft(draggedImage) + offset.X;
            double NewYPos = Canvas.GetTop(draggedImage) + offset.Y;
            Rooms[listBoxRooms.SelectedIndex].Furniture[listBoxFurniture.SelectedIndex].XPos = NewXPos;
            Rooms[listBoxRooms.SelectedIndex].Furniture[listBoxFurniture.SelectedIndex].YPos = NewYPos;
            Canvas.SetLeft(draggedImage, NewXPos);
            Canvas.SetTop(draggedImage, NewYPos);

        }
    }
```

FurnitureImage is just an Image with 3 fields: IsDraggable, XPos and YPos. I have tried creating a new thread for the CanvasRoomMouseLeftButtonDown method but this threw the exception that the object could not be accesses because it is on a different thread. I looked around online and found Dispatcher.Invoke(), however this did not work alongside the new thread - the program continued to freeze. Is there a better way to make sure that the only image I can move is the one corresponding to what's selected from the listbox, and how do I fix my multithreading issue?

Comment: Why you start new `Thread` in event handler? And why you use Dispatcher?

Comment: @apocalypse So if I remove the dispatcher, where is the correct place to start the new thread?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You didn't start a new thread. You have just used `ThreadStart` delegate. Why? What will happen if you remove `Distapcher.BeginInvoke`? `//Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();` - it will freeze your main thread if uncommented.

Comment: lookup DragDrop.DoDragDrop

Comment: I actually have no idea why the `//Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();` is there. I haven't done multithreading before so I don't have a reason for using it aside from finding it as a solution to another issue and trying to see if it will work for mine. After I get this working I will read up on multithreading properly

Comment: _the object could not be accesses because it is on a different thread_; OK, which object are you talking about and how is it initialized? Please provide this related code too.